# Can it realistically happen that for an UDP socket, the send function doesn't fail, but still writes less data than requested?

Tags: c, sockets, udp, posix, send

From `man 2 sendto`:

> On success, these calls return the number of bytes sent.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.

Am I to understand that failure to write all data is not treated as a failure of these functions, therefore it realistically may happen that when writing to an UDP socket, the `send()` function writes less data than requested, but the reason of this failure is not specified in `errno`?

Or can I presume that `send()` will either return `-1` and set `errno` appropriately, or return the number of bytes requested to send?

In other words: Is this error handling code sufficient:

```
if(send(udp_sock_fd, buf, buflen, 0) == -1) {
  int err = errno;
  fprintf(stderr, "Send failed:\n");
  fprintf(stderr, strerror(err));
}
```

Or is it rather necessary to write something like that:

```
ssize_t bytes_send = send(udp_sock_fd, buf, buflen, 0);
if(bytes_send == -1) {
  int err = errno;
  fprintf(stderr, "Send failed:\n");
  fprintf(stderr, strerror(err));
} else if(bytes_send < buflen) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Incomplete send for unknown reason.\n");
}
```

Comment: Good question, and I'm curious as well. Please slap anyone who tells you to "just try it".

Comment: just try it. :)

Comment: @jnbbender *slap* ;P On a more serious note, I’m not sure how can it be helpful, I don’t suppose I can provoke such a situation, and no amount of failed attempts will prove this situation cannot happen.

Comment: There's no point in having a datagram protocol if it gets split up at application level!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no concept of sending just part of a datagram.  It either all goes, or none of it goes.  The OS or network drivers will not split the datagram for you.  Returning the character count sent must just be a courtesy, to fall inline with other `send` API functions.

Also from the man page:

> For `sendto()`, if the message is too long to pass atomically through the underlying protocol, the error `EMSGSIZE` is returned, and the message is not transmitted.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, @Paul Bentley has already provided the correct answer, but in case you're worried that -- even though this is never supposed to happen -- there might be some rare error condition where it does, it may be helpful to note that at least for a particular implementation (Linux), the code for `udp_sendmsg` in `net/ipv4/udp.c` (which is what's ultimately called for a `send` on a UDP socket) has only one exit that can return a non-negative value, and it returns the length supplied by the caller:

```
int udp_sendmsg(struct sock *sk, struct msghdr *msg, size_t len)
{
        ... code that doesn't modify len ...
out:
        ...
        if (!err)
               return len;
        ...
}
```